# Django OAuth Toolkit and Django Rest Swagger Integration

Tags: python, django, swagger, django-swagger, oauth2-toolkit

I'm using [OAuthToolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) and DjangoRestSwagger. I've created an application using Django Admin, and now I've `client_id` and `client_secret`.

I want to generate the token using `client_id` and `client_secret`. Currently, I use `curl` to generate the token.

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -u"client_id:client_secret" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

How can I do it using the Swagger docs.? Basically, how can  integrate third party(OAuthToolkit) API URLs with Swagger?

Currently, I've an `Authorize` button which takes `api_key` value, ie the token.

Here's my Swagger settings.

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'token': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'AUTHORIZATION',
            'in': 'header',
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not certain about `django-rest-swagger` but if you are looking for an alternative with gauranteed support for `oauth` you can use `drf-yasg` (yet another swagger generator)

Documentation for [yasg adding oauth paths to swagger](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#describing-authentication-schemes)